# Asp.Net Mvc Consume Url posting json data

Tags: web-services, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I was wondering if anyone had any pointers for parsing json data consumed from a URL in Asp.Net.  I've found plenty of docs about Model Binding json datatypes but this is coming from a URL and I cant seem to find an example for that.  The closest thing I've found is `datacontractjsonserializer` but again, I cant seem to find an example of that in context with a URL outputting the json data.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean "URL outputting the json data"? Is this an external API you are consuming? Maybe give an example of what your doing, and the JSON that is coming back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class. You start by defining a model class which will hold the data. So let's suppose that the remote URL returns the following JSON:

```
{ name: 'John', addresses: [ { city: 'Paris' }, { city: 'London' } ] }
```

which could be represented by this model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address[] Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize the received JSON back to the model:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
// TODO: Fetch the JSON from a remote URL
var json = "{name: 'foo', addresses: [{city: 'Paris'}, {city: 'London'}]}";
var person = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(json);
```

---

UPDATE:

In order to fetch the JSON from remote url you could use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string json = client.DownloadString("http://someurl.com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have so far. A product of all answers that I get here in stack.
The idea is to get the json value from external web service and publish it in my controller as a json values and I dont have to create model for it. Hope this helps.

public class ApiJson: Controller
    {

```
    public JsonResult getUser()
    {

        WebClient client = WebClient();
        NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
        data.Add("param1", "value1");    

        byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://localhost:9000/", data);

        String json = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(json);

        return Json(item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }




}
```